# Select Products/Events in Multiple Categories using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

As an example, I need a query to find events that are categorised as :

either category ID 1, 2 or 3 (let's say these are running, swimming, cycling)
AND
category ID 15 (let's say this is 5km distance)

It could equally be extended to 15 or 16 perhaps (5km or 10km)

I have three tables : event, event_event_categories and event_categories

event_event_catgories is designed as you'd expect with the primary key from each related table:

```
event_id, category_id
---------------------
2345      1
2456      2
7893      3
2345      15
```

event_categories is designed as follows with a parent category

```
category_id, category_name, parent_category_name
------------------------------------------------
1            Running        Sport
2            Swimming       Sport
3            Cycling        Sport
...
15           5km            Distance
16           10km           Distance
```

What I essentially need back are events that are in plain english:

(Running or swimming or cycling) AND (5km)

The distinction for AND is made as soon as a parent category is different and I can handle this outside of MySQL if necessary.

In the example above, only event no. 2345 should be returned from the query.

I've got the query this far but I'm unsure how to proceed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.event_name, e.address_town, e.address_county, eo.event_organiser_name, COUNT(DISTINCT ec.id) as catCount
FROM event e 
INNER JOIN event_event_categories ecm on e.id = ecm.event_id
INNER JOIN event_category ec on ec.id = ecm.event_category_id
INNER JOIN event_organiser eo on e.event_organiser_id = eo.id
WHERE ec.id IN (1,2,3,15)
AND e.start_date_time >= '2016-01-01'
AND e.start_date_time <= '2016-12-31'
AND e.enabled = true
GROUP BY ecm.event_id
ORDER BY catCount DESC, e.start_date_time;
```

I hope I've explained that well enough and would really like to hear any and all suggestions.

Comment: The general GROUP BY tip: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." (Older MySQL versions don't care about this, but newer ones do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT e.event_name, e.address_town, e.address_county, eo.event_organiser_name
FROM event e INNER JOIN
     event_event_categories ecm
     on e.id = ecm.event_id INNER JOIN
     event_category ec
     on ec.id = ecm.event_category_id INNER JOIN
     event_organiser eo
     on e.event_organiser_id = eo.id
WHERE ec.id IN (1, 2, 3, 15) AND
      e.start_date_time >= '2016-01-01' AND 
      e.start_date_time <= '2016-12-31' AND
      e.enabled = true
GROUP BY ecm.event_id
HAVING SUM(ec.id IN (1, 2, 3)) > 0 AND
       SUM(ec.id = 15) > 0;
```

This chooses events that are at least one of "1", "2", or "3".  If you want exactly one match to these, then use:

```
HAVING SUM(ec.id IN (1, 2, 3)) = 1 AND
       SUM(ec.id = 15) > 0;
```

The use of the `HAVING` clause for this type of query is very powerful. I call this type of query "set-within-set" because you are looking at sets of categories within events.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll give that a go as soon as I can.  I notice the ORDER BY clause is dropped from your suggested answer.  Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Early testing shows this is just what I need but I'll confirm when I'm sure.  On your second HAVING clause example, did you mean to say SUM(ec.id IN (1, 2, 3)) = 1.

Comment: @RobinM . . . Yes I did.  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks again for your help on this.  Fully integrated and working exactly as desired.